# Adding multiple markers from external json to Google Map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I receive json data from a server and need to add them to a google map. It works fine, however, I only see one marker and I assume every time I add a marker it changes it to new coordinates and doesnt add an extra marker. How can I define markers as an array?

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

var entry = data.feed.entry;


$(entry).each(function(){
   for (var prop in this["gsx$instruments"]) {
    //alert(this["gsx$instruments"][prop]);
    listContacts(this["gsx$instruments"][prop])
        var myLatLng = {lat: Number(this["gsx$ycor"][prop]), lng: Number(this["gsx$xcor"][prop])};

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: myLatLng
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title: this["gsx$instruments"][prop]
        });

   }
  // Column names are name, age, etc.
  //$('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$instruments.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$type.$t+'</p>');
});

});
```

Comment: Looks like you are overwriting the `map` on each iteration. Remove the map creation from the `each` loop.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, including sample data and any HTML/CSS required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new function `addMarker` and use that function to include markers also keep the map variable outside the ajax call as well. updated code below

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: {lat: LAT, lng: LONG}
        });
function addMarker(position, map, title){
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: title
    });
}

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {

var entry = data.feed.entry;


$(entry).each(function(){
   for (var prop in this["gsx$instruments"]) {
    //alert(this["gsx$instruments"][prop]);
    listContacts(this["gsx$instruments"][prop])
        var myLatLng = {lat: Number(this["gsx$ycor"][prop]), lng: Number(this["gsx$xcor"][prop])};

        addMarker(myLatLng,map,this["gsx$instruments"][prop]);

   }
  // Column names are name, age, etc.
  //$('.results').prepend('<h2>'+this.gsx$instruments.$t+'</h2><p>'+this.gsx$type.$t+'</p>');
});

});
```

Comment: Is it the first marker in your list of the last, can you identify?

Comment: If you the development page link, that will be very helpful to identify the problem.

Comment: Try the updated code, keep the map variable outside the ajax, initiate is with initial longiture and latitude and it should work

Comment: Now, all appears but one blink and go away?

Comment: Make sure the map initialization happens only onces, e.g. var map = new google.maps.Map( line should be only inside a document ready function. you never redefine the Map. If you have link to your full we code i can investigate further.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake it was loading again in my index.html.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you first need to add the `markers` to an `array of markers`

Suppose you have `JSON` providing the `markers` and supposing each `marker` has a `name` and `coordinates` attributes

```
function formatMarkers (){
  // Loop through all of the JSON entries provided in the response
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {

     var markers = markersArray[i];
     // Create popup windows for each record
     var contentString = '<p><b>Name</b>: ' + markers.name + '</p>';

     // Converts each of the JSON records into Google Maps Location format
     formattedMarkers.push({
                    latlon: new google.maps.LatLng( markers.coordinates[1], markers.coordinates[0] ),
                        message: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: contentString,
                            maxWidth: 320
                        }),
                        username: markers.name
                 });
    }
    return formattedMarkers;
}
```

Then you need to render each of them

```
formattedMarkers.forEach(function (n) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                       position: n.latlon,
                                       map: map,
                                       icon: icon
                                      });

   // For each marker created, add a listener that checks for clicks
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
          // When clicked, open the selected marker's message
               n.message.open(map, marker);
   });
   marker.setMap(map);
}
```

I hope I've been helpful.